# Functions of variables in facet_wrap

Tags: r, ggplot2

Suppose I have the following dataframe:

```
df <- data.frame(x = sample(1:100,100,T),y = sample(1:100,100,T), z = rep(1:4,25))
```

So it looks like this

```
> head(df,10)
    x  y z
1  57 65 1
2  78 29 2
3  22 49 3
4  61 67 4
5   8 95 1
6  46 13 2
7  32 70 3
8  21 87 4
9  66 76 1
10 90 81 2
```

And suppose I want to make a faceted plot, using `z` as a categorical variable:

```
plot <- ggplot(df, aes(x, y)) + geom_point()
plot + facet_wrap(~z)
```

The code above actually does the job and makes a plot with 4 facets. But what if I need to make some experimental plots, say, place points with z equal to 1, or 2 to one facet and other points to second. My first thought was

```
plot + facet_wrap(~(z<3))
```

and it returned an error:

> Error in layout_base(data, vars, drop = drop) : 
>     At least one layer must contain all variables used for facetting

So, as I understand this categorical variable should be present in the dataframe. This issue can be fixed, e.g. in the following way:

```
ggplot(mutate(df, v = (z < 3)), aes(x, y)) + geom_point() + facet_wrap(~v)
```

But it is much less convenient than the previous version could have been. Especially when `plot` is quite complicated.
I'm wondering why can't we use functions of variables for faceting while it is allowed for mappings. And the second question is, maybe someone sees a better approach, than the one I made with `mutate`.

Comment: Your approach is fine by me. I am sure that `facet_wrap` wouldn't allow such lambdas, and I don't think there's a simpler solution.

Comment: @tonytonov >'I am sure that facet_wrap wouldn't allow such lambdas' - any suggestions why?

Comment: Well, it was designed to mimic `?formula`, which has no such semantics.

Comment: @tonytonov Thank you for your answer. But it looks like it is not an unsolvable problem. For example, there is `tabular` package for making summary tables. Table format is specified by formula object and functions are allowed here. As an example: `tabular(data = iris, Species ~ (log(Sepal.Length)) * mean)` calculates mean values of `log(Sepal.Length)` for each species.

Comment: Sorry, package is called `tables`, but function is `tabular`.

Comment: For sure, potentially one could add any semantics and override `facet_wrap` to add that functionality, but a) that's not a simple task, b) adding a dummy variable looks natural and requires zero additional effort.